# My discord.py bot cannot check roles in command

Tags: python

```
@client.command()
async def expelliarmus(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  if member.have_roles("protego"):
   await ctx.send("Protego yapan birine saldıramazsın.")
  else:
   duelrole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="düellocu")
   await member.remove_roles(duelrole)
   await ctx.send("ASASI UÇTU!  blablabla")
   await asyncio.sleep(30)
   await member.add_roles(duelrole)
   await ctx.send("Asasını geri aldı!!")
```

I'm building a Discord bot and I want the command not to work if the user has the role named Protego. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

u need to definite exception for unregistered a role 'protego'.